# gtk-launch .desktop is not using custom icon

Tags: unity, command-line, icons, .desktop

I copied my .desktop shorcut to `user_home+"/.local/share/applications/"` then going to terminal and typing in `gtk-launch nameOfMyDesktopFile` it launchs it, but it doesn't take the custom icon. I'm trying to make it take the custom icon as it should, as this is how it behaves if I double click it.

Here is a video showing that when I double click on my .desktop "Mozilla Firefox - dev" it opens it with the custom icon i gave it, which we see is the "beta" label across the bottom right of the firefox logo.

part of importance starts at 1min 53sec of this screencast i recorded:

http://youtu.be/1MeB-H7mGsc?t=1m53s

the contents of my .desktop file is this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mozilla Firefox - dev
Type=Application
Comment=Web Application
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -no-remote -P dev
Icon=/home/noit/Desktop/ff-channel-base-iconsets/beta/beta512.png
Name[en_US]=Mozilla Firefox - dev
```

We see that it launches firefox with some command line arguments.

Please help me to get gtk-launch of .desktop i copied to use its custom icon. Thank you!!